# What will updating a production server to Summer '14 do?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, ide, metadata, summer14

I'm trying to delete a trigger off production, but all my efforts to do so have been met with failure. My most recent attempt should work, but the IDE is first asking me to upgrade my version of the code from production. What will this do to my data? The comparison looks like the new version is completely empty, does this mean all my metadata in these objects are going to disappear?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Are you using Eclipse to create and deploy the destructive changeset for you?

Comment: I was using Eclipse to edit the metadata of the trigger, and then save it to server.

Comment: @DashboardReport - Your IDE is most likely at a newer version than the code stored in its repository. Upgrading the code should only affect the code on your local repository and not affect anything in production. A screenshot of what you are seeing would also be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Eclipse is saying that the **project** must be updated to the latest version, not the server code. Which means your Eclipse project will be refreshed from the server to match what has already happened to the server.

You can't upgrade your production **server** to Summer '14. That upgrade just happens when Salesforce wills it. And it has already happened.

If you're nervous (like I was the first couple of times Eclipse said this to me) you can abandon your existing project and just create a new Eclipse project pointing at the same Org.

Then you can go ahead and perform your delete.

Comment: Ill have to try that, but the project I was using was a new project, Ill try cleaning my workspace and make a new one, and post back here. May be after the holidays, office has strange hours this time of year.